# Are Epicurean 'pleasures of mind' clearly stated as being of a unique or universal nature?

Tags: mind-body, epicurus, pain-and-pleasure, universal-and-particulars

I read that Epicurean 'pleasures of body' are unique to each individual.  i.e. each person experiences the "pleasures of the body" in a different way.

I wondered whether Epicurean 'pleasures of mind' unique to each individual, or are they universal?

Is it clearly stated anywhere in the original text? Or scholarship?

Thanks!

Comment: See [Epicurus: Types of Pleasure](https://iep.utm.edu/epicur/#SH5b)

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the arrow to reward the contributor and the checkmark to select what you feel is the best answer.